# Using gsub to substitute a variable with another variable which is a value from a function call

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a function which substitutes actual values with some pattern from a file. The objective I'm trying to achieve here is to call a function which uses `gsub` to find and replace the string in a way that the substitution value is basically coming from another function call.

```
$ cat pat-file
name         10101010
phone        10101010
code         10101010
bankaccount  1010101010101

$ cat data_sub.sh

abc()
{
awk '
function mask(str, str_masked) {
    for (j=1; j<=length(str); j++) {
        if (substr(masks[i], j, 1)==1) {
            c = substr(str, j, 1)
        } else {
            c = "*"
        }

        str_masked = str_masked c
    }

    return str_masked
}

FNR == NR {
    tags[NR-1] = $1
    masks[NR-1] = $2
}

FNR != NR {
    line = $0

    for (i in tags) {
        regex = "<"tags[i]">[^<]+</"tags[i]">"
        masked_line = ""
        l = length(tags[i])
        while (match(line, regex) > 0) {
            fulltag = substr(line, RSTART, RLENGTH)
            tagval = substr(fulltag, l+3, RLENGTH-l-l-5)
            fulltag_masked = "<"tags[i]">" mask(tagval) "</"tags[i]">"
            masked_line = masked_line substr(line, 1, RSTART-1) fulltag_masked

            line = substr(line, RSTART + RLENGTH)
        }

        line = masked_line line
    }

    print line
}' "$@" pat-file file-1 > output_file
}

abc
```

The `tagval` variable stores the value of the XML tag which gets masked inside the XML but as it is present outside the XML as well, I need to mask those values too. See the input file

**file-1**

```
This is a demo data = ABCD
This is a demo data = XYCD
This is a demo data = ABCD
This is a demo data = BLAH
This is a demo data = ABCD
This is a demo data = MEH
This is a demo data = ABCD
This is a demo data = ABCD
This is a demo data = ABCD
This is a demo data = ABCD and MEH
This is a demo data <tag changed="yes"<name>ABCD</name><phone>98762123</phone><code>MEH</code><bankaccount>4563728495847</bankaccount></tag>
This is a demo data <tag changed="yes"<name>ABCD</name><phone>98762123</phone><code>MEH</code><bankaccount>4563728495847</bankaccount></tag>
This is a demo data <tag changed="yes"<name>ABCD</name><phone>98762123</phone><code>MEH</code><bankaccount>4563728495847</bankaccount></tag>
```

The logic is simple and pretty straight forward i.e store all the extracted tag value that get masked, then perform the same masking algorithm on those values but outside XML. How can I achieve this?

**Output file**

```
This is a demo data = ABCD
This is a demo data = XYCD
This is a demo data = ABCD
This is a demo data = BLAH
This is a demo data = ABCD
This is a demo data = MEH
This is a demo data = ABCD
This is a demo data = ABCD
This is a demo data = ABCD
This is a demo data = ABCD and MEH
This is a demo data <tag changed="yes"<name>A*C*</name><phone>9*7*2*2*</phone><code>M*H</code><bankaccount>4*6*7*8*9*8*7</bankaccount></tag>
This is a demo data <tag changed="yes"<name>A*C*</name><phone>9*7*2*2*</phone><code>M*H</code><bankaccount>4*6*7*8*9*8*7</bankaccount></tag>
This is a demo data <tag changed="yes"<name>A*C*</name><phone>9*7*2*2*</phone><code>M*H</code><bankaccount>4*6*7*8*9*8*7</bankaccount></tag>
```

**Expected Output file**

```
This is a demo data = A*C*
This is a demo data = XYCD
This is a demo data = A*C*
This is a demo data = BLAH
This is a demo data = A*C*
This is a demo data = M*H
This is a demo data = A*C*
This is a demo data = A*C*
This is a demo data = A*C*
This is a demo data = A*C* and M*H
This is a demo data <tag changed="yes"<name>A*C*</name><phone>9*7*2*2*</phone><code>M*H</code><bankaccount>4*6*7*8*9*8*7</bankaccount></tag>
This is a demo data <tag changed="yes"<name>A*C*</name><phone>9*7*2*2*</phone><code>M*H</code><bankaccount>4*6*7*8*9*8*7</bankaccount></tag>
This is a demo data <tag changed="yes"<name>A*C*</name><phone>9*7*2*2*</phone><code>M*H</code><bankaccount>4*6*7*8*9*8*7</bankaccount></tag>
```

Comment: please update the question to include the (wrong?) output geneated by your code

Comment: an aside ... the function feeds `"$@" pat-file file-1` to `awk`, but if `$@` is non-empty then `pat-file` no longer matches on `FNR == NR` and your `tags[]/masks[]` arrays get filled with ... what?  what's the purpose of `$@` and what's the expected contents of this reference (if non-empty)?

Comment: what's the expected max size (MBytes, # of lines) of the input files (`pat-file` and `file-1`)? do you have access to `GNU awk` and if so what version (`awk --version`)? are all non-tagged lines of the exact format: `This is a demo data = ABCD` and if not, how do we know which strings (in said lines) need to be masked or do we mask *any/all* strings that have a match in `pat-file`? should we mask `ABCDXYZ` or `ABCD-XYZ`? where did `This is a demo data = A*C* and M*H` come from since there is no input linae `This is a demo data = ABCD and MEH`? please update the question with these details

Comment: what to do if a string is wider than a mask string (eg, `name` = `Winkelstein` (11 chars) but the mask is only `10101010` (8 chars)? assuming tags could have different masks, what if a string shows up under two different tags (eg, `name=node=NAMENODE`), which mask are we supposed to use?

Comment: Hi @markp-fuso , for name = Winkelstein and masking pattern as 10101010 , it will be W*n*e*s**** since the code only prints the value when there's a 1 present in the pat-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- if a string shows up under different tags (eg, `name=ABCD` and `code=ABCD`) then the 1st mask found by `awk` will be used to mask the string (ie, we won't prioritize the order in which tag/mask pairs are processed)
- strings (to be masked) could show up anywhere in a line
- when matching for non-tag substrings we'll use `awk` word boundaries (eg, when masking `ABCD` we'll also mask `ABCD-XYZ` but we won't mask `ABCDABCD` nor `ABCD_XYZ`)
- both files, along with an array of value/masked-value pairs, will fit in memory
- if OP provides a mask of `111111111...` (all `1's`) we'll go ahead and perform the (effective) no-op operation

General operation:

- process input file (eg, `file-1`) looking for 'tag' entries
- if we find any matching 'tag' entries we'll apply the proposed mask to the corresponding value
- for each value that is masked we'll keep a copy of said value, and its mask, in a new array
- for repeat values we'll apply the saved mask
- all lines, with or without tags/masked-data, are saved in an array
- `END` processing runs through our array of lines again, looking for any (word-boundaried) strings that were previously masked and if found, replace with the saved mask value
- in the case of a mask of `11111111...` (all `1's`) this `END` processing will re-mask the 'tag' entries, too (still, effectively, a no-op)
- all lines are then sent to stdout

Adding some lines to the sample input file:

```
$ cat file-1
This is a demo data = ABCD
This is a demo data = XYCD
This is a demo data = ABCD
This is a demo data = BLAH
This is a demo data = ABCD
This is a demo data = MEH
This is a demo data = ABCD
This is a demo data = ABCD
This is a demo data = ABCD
This is a demo data = ABCD and MEH
This is a demo data <tag changed="yes"<name>ABCD</name><phone>98762123</phone><code>MEH</code><bankaccount>4563728495847</bankaccount></tag>
This is a demo data <tag changed="yes"<name>ABCD</name><phone>98762123</phone><code>MEH</code><bankaccount>4563728495847</bankaccount></tag>
This is a demo data <tag changed="yes"<name>ABCD</name><phone>98762123</phone><code>MEH</code><bankaccount>4563728495847</bankaccount></tag>
#####################
# some more lines ...
#####################
This is a demo data = ABCD and XYCD
This is a demo data = XYCD and MEH
This is ABCD and MEH demo data <tag changed="yes"<name>Winkelstein</name><phone>98762123</phone><code>MEH</code><bankaccount>4563728495847</bankaccount></tag>
One last line ABCD ABCD-XYZ ABCDABCD ABCD_XYZ
```

One idea building on OP's current `awk` code:

```
awk '
function mask(str, str_masked) {
    for (j=1; j<=length(str); j++) {
        if (substr(masks[tag], j, 1) == 1)
           c = substr(str, j, 1)
        else
           c = "*"
        str_masked = str_masked c
    }
    return str_masked
}

FNR == NR { masks[$1] = $2; next }
          { line = $0

            for (tag in masks) {
                regex = "<" tag ">[^<]+</" tag ">"
                masked_line = ""
                len = length(tag)

                while (match(line, regex) > 0) {
                      val = substr(line, RSTART+(len+2), RLENGTH-(len+2)-(len+3))
                      masked[val]= (val in masked) ? masked[val] : mask(val)
                      masked_line = masked_line substr(line, 1, RSTART-1) "<" tag ">" masked[val] "</" tag ">"
                      line = substr(line, RSTART + RLENGTH)
                }
                line = masked_line line
            }
            lines[FNR]=line
        }

END     { for (i=1;i<=FNR;i++) {
              for (val in masked) {
                  regex="\\<" val "\\>"
                  gsub(regex,masked[val],lines[i])
              }
              print lines[i]
          }
        }
' pat-file file-1
```

This generates:

```
This is a demo data = A*C*
This is a demo data = XYCD
This is a demo data = A*C*
This is a demo data = BLAH
This is a demo data = A*C*
This is a demo data = M*H
This is a demo data = A*C*
This is a demo data = A*C*
This is a demo data = A*C*
This is a demo data = A*C* and M*H
This is a demo data <tag changed="yes"<name>A*C*</name><phone>9*7*2*2*</phone><code>M*H</code><bankaccount>4*6*7*8*9*8*7</bankaccount></tag>
This is a demo data <tag changed="yes"<name>A*C*</name><phone>9*7*2*2*</phone><code>M*H</code><bankaccount>4*6*7*8*9*8*7</bankaccount></tag>
This is a demo data <tag changed="yes"<name>A*C*</name><phone>9*7*2*2*</phone><code>M*H</code><bankaccount>4*6*7*8*9*8*7</bankaccount></tag>
#####################
# some more lines ...
#####################
This is a demo data = A*C* and XYCD
This is a demo data = XYCD and M*H
This is A*C* and M*H demo data <tag changed="yes"<name>W*n*e*s****</name><phone>9*7*2*2*</phone><code>M*H</code><bankaccount>4*6*7*8*9*8*7</bankaccount></tag>
One last line A*C* A*C*-XYZ ABCDABCD ABCD_XYZ
```